# How to add text input to dropzone upload

Tags: templates, upload, custom-fields, dropzone.js

I'd like to allow users to submit a title for each file that is dragged into Dropzone that will be inputted into a text input. But i don't know how to add it. Everyone can help me?

[image: dropzone upload]

This is my html code code

```
  <form id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone">
  <div class="dropzone-previews"></div> <!-- this is were the previews should be shown. -->

  <!-- Now setup your input fields -->
  <input type="email" name="username" id="username" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

  <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
</form>
```

And this is my script code

```
<script>
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

  // The configuration we've talked about above
  url: "upload.php",
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 100,
  maxFiles: 100,
  maxFilesize:10,//MB

  // The setting up of the dropzone
  init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;

    // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
    this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      myDropzone.processQueue();
    });

    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
    this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
      // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
      // Hide the success button or the complete form.

    });
    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
      // Redirect user or notify of success.

    });
    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
      // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
      // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
    });
  },
  accept: function (file, done) {
        //maybe do something here for showing a dialog or adding the fields to the preview?
    },
 addRemoveLinks: true
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you find any solution to do it? If so, please share!

Answer (score 17):

You can actually provide a template for Dropzone to render the image preview as well as any extra fields. In your case, I would suggest taking the default template or making your own, and simply adding the input field there:

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
    <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>
    <div class="dz-details">
        <div class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size></span></div>
        <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
    <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title">
</div>
```

The full default preview template can be found in the source code of dropzone.js.

---

Then you can simply pass your custom template to Dropzone as a string for the previewTemplate key of the option parameters. For example:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#yourId', {
    previewTemplate: "..."
});
```

As long as your element is a form, Dropzone will automatically include all inputs in the xhr request parameters.

Comment: This answers exactly what the question asked. just add the html template he uses to the "previewTemplate" section in the javascript and you're done!

Answer (score 5):

I am doing something fairly similar. I accomplished it by just adding a modal dialog with jquery that opens when a file is added. Hope it helps.

```
 this.on("addedfile", function() { 
   $("#dialog-form").dialog("open"); 
 });
```

Comment: It has everything to do with it. My solution is slightly different that what OP asked for, and I'm well aware of that. However OP should be able to use the same wrapper to append whatever html they would like to the file added. Either that or they can go into dropzone and make a bunch of changes themselves to try to hack it in as a standard piece of the library. I had originally started down that path myself, this was just easier.

Answer (score 5):

In my answer, substitute your "title" field for my "description" field.

Add input text or textarea to the preview template. For example:

```
<div class="table table-striped files" id="previews">

  <div id="template" class="file-row">
    <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
    <div>
        <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
        <input class="text" type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Searchable Description">
    </div>  ... etc.
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in the sending function, append the associated data:

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {

  // Get and pass description field data
    var str = file.previewElement.querySelector("#description").value;
    formData.append("description", str);
    ...
});
```

Finally, in the processing script that does the actual upload, receive the data from the POST:

```
$description = (isset($_POST['description']) && ($_POST['description'] <> 'undefined')) ? $_POST['description'] : '';
```

You may now store your description (or title or what have you) in a Database etc.

Hope this works for you. It was a son-of-a-gun to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Manto. My first answer. You made it much better!

Answer (score 3):

This one is kind of hidden in the docs but the place to add additional data is in the "sending" event. The sending event is called just before each file is sent and gets the xhr object and the formData objects as second and third parameters, so you can modify them.

So basically you'll want to add those two additional params and then append the additional data inside "sending" function or in your case "sendingmultiple". You can use jQuery or just plain js to get the values. So it should look something like:

```
this.on("sendingmultiple", function(file, xhr, formData) {
      //Add additional data to the upload
      formData.append('username', $('#username').val());
      formData.append('password', $('#password').val());       
    });
```

Comment: only problem with this is that you don't have access to the event target, so you can't easily get an associated element if you're doing inputs per template.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone", { 
    url: 'yourUploader.php',
    init: function () {
        this.on(
            "addedfile", function(file) {
              caption = file.caption == undefined ? "" : file.caption;
              file._captionLabel = Dropzone.createElement("<p>File Info:</p>")
              file._captionBox = Dropzone.createElement("<input id='"+file.filename+"' type='text' name='caption' value="+caption+" >");
              file.previewElement.appendChild(file._captionLabel);
              file.previewElement.appendChild(file._captionBox);
        }),
        this.on(
            "sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
            formData.append('yourPostName',file._captionBox.value);
        })
  }
});
```

yourUploader.php :

```
<?php 
  // Your Dropzone file named 
  $myfileinfo = $_POST['yourPostName'];
  // And your files in $_FILES
?>
```

Comment: to append for multiple request suppose one upload more than one file and you have to show description for each file

                         `formData.append('description[]',file._captionBox.value);`

Comment: I was able to resolve that issue with your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
    url: "Enter your url",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false,

    init: function () {
        let totalFiles = 0,
            completeFiles = 0;
        this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
            totalFiles += 1;
            localStorage.setItem('totalItem',totalFiles);
            caption = file.caption == undefined ? "" : file.caption;
            file._captionLabel = Dropzone.createElement("<p>File Info:</p>")
            file._captionBox = Dropzone.createElement("<textarea rows='4' cols='15' id='"+file.filename+"' name='caption' value="+caption+" ></textarea>");
            file.previewElement.appendChild(file._captionLabel);
            file.previewElement.appendChild(file._captionBox);
            // this.autoProcessQueue = true;
        });
        document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            const myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement(".dropzone");
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
        this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
            console.log('total files is '+localStorage.getItem('totalItem'));
                formData.append('description[]',file._captionBox.value);
        })

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to keep the automatic and send datas (like an ID or something that does not depend on the user) you can just add a setTimeout to "addedfile":

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    }, 10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution for me and so I am going to write it down in the hope it might help other people also. The basic approach is to have an new input in the preview container and setting it via the css class if the file data is incoming by succeeding upload process or at init from existing files.

You have to integrate the following code in your one.. I just skipped some lines which might necessary for let it work.

```
photowolke = {
    render_file:function(file)
    {
    caption = file.title == undefined ? "" : file.title;
    file.previewElement.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].value = caption;
    //change the name of the element even for sending with post later
    file.previewElement.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].id = file.id + '_title';
    file.previewElement.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].name = file.id + '_title';
    },
    init: function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
            previewNode.id = "";
            var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
            previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);
            photowolke.myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#files_upload", {
                init: function() {
                    thisDropzone = this;
                    this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                        //just copy the title from the response of the server
                        file.title=responseText.photo_title;
                        //and call with the "new" file the renderer function
                        photowolke.render_file(file);
                    });
                    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                       photowolke.render_file(file);
                    });
                },
                previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
            });
            //this is for loading from a local json to show existing files
            $.each(photowolke.arr_photos, function(key, value) {
                var mockFile = {
                    name: value.name,
                    size: value.size,
                    title: value.title,
                    id: value.id,
                    owner_id: value.owner_id
                };
                photowolke.myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
                // And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:
                photowolke.myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, value.path);
                // Make sure that there is no progress bar, etc...
                photowolke.myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
            });
        });
    },
};
```

And there is my template for the preview:

```
 <div class="dropzone-previews" id="files_upload" name="files_upload"> 
         <div id="template" class="file-row">
    <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
    <div>
        <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail width="150" /></span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="text" data-dz-title class="title" placeholder="title"/>

        <p class="name" data-dz-name></p><p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
        <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
    </div>
    <div>

        <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
        </div>
    </div>


  </div>
```