# {Multi Drag-and-drop} How to display a combobox for each file before upload

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, web-frontend, dropzone

I'm using [dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) for uploading files on my server.
I can drag and drop multi files, and correctly send it with a post request.

I need for each files uploaded, an information relative about them.
I would like to show up a combobox for each element before sending them to the server.

1./ Select a range of files

2./ Drop them into the drop zone

---

3./ Displaying a div with a combobox and the name of the file (for each file)

4./ Select the option (for each file)

---

5./ Send it to the server in the same request. (for each file)

At this moment, i can only drag and drop files, and they are uploading when they are dropped. One request per file.

I would like at least, get the file, with the value of the combobox in my post request.

I used to solve problems by "myself", but i'm starting front programing, and i miss a lot of concept to find a good way to think.

Do you have any idea to help me ?

Thank you

("my" front code for the drag'n drop)

```
<div class="meter">
    <span class="roller"></span> //progress bar
</div>
<input hidden id="file" name="file"/>
<div id="dropzone">
    <form action="/upload" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropzone.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropzone.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood more things about dropzonejs, and i found the good way to search.

[How to add text input to dropzone upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391134/how-to-add-text-input-to-dropzone-upload)

Problem solved